# Parsing XML with SAX/Python + no validation

Tags: python, xml, validation, sax

I am new to python and I'm trying to parse a XML file with SAX *without* validating it.

The head of my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE n:document SYSTEM "schema.dtd">
<n:document....
```

and I've tried to parse it with python 2.5.2:

```
from xml.sax import make_parser, handler
import sys

parser = make_parser()
parser.setFeature(handler.feature_namespaces,True)
parser.setFeature(handler.feature_validation,False)
parser.setContentHandler(handler.ContentHandler())
parser.parse(sys.argv[1])
```

but I got an error:

```
python doc.py document.xml
(...)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 244, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: schema.dtd
```

I don't want the SAX parser to look for a schema. Where am I wrong ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

expatreader considers the DTD external subset as an external general entity. So the feature you want is:

```
parser.setFeature(handler.feature_external_ges, False)
```

However, it's a bit dodgy pointing the DTD external subset to a non-existant URL; as this shows, it's not only validating parsers that read it.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem. I still get the ValueError unknown url type. Maybe something changed in python3.

Comment: @ThatAintWorking assuming you have something like `<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "foo.dtd"` try creating a dtd file in the same dir. the name should be "foo.dtd".  at the very least it should contain `<!ELEMENT foo \n(bar)>` you may need to replace the "\n" with an actual carriage return.

Comment: @16num Sorry, I don't even remember the context of this issue anymore.